# update textarea content on click on an input button

Tags: javascript

i want update textarea content onclock on a input button

for example:

```
<input type="button" value="Reply" onclick="update('Ahmed')">
<textarea id="comment_content"></textarea>
//i want set textarea content to @/Ahmed/ onclick on the above button
//example for the javascript function
function update(var){
getElementByID('comment_content') = '@/'.var.'/'
//set the textarea to @/Ahmed/
}
```

I have another question.. i want onclick on the button, i want send the user to the end of the page ( to the new_comment div )

i want javascript code, not jquery

Comment: You are missing `value` in `getElementByID('comment_content')`

Comment: @Sarfraz i am very noob in javascript.. and this function is fully of errors/missings but it just for example,, for better explain for my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function update(val)
{
   document.getElementById('comment_content').value = val;
}
```

Scrolling to the bottom is:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Comment: thank you very much.. both is works fine, but how to use it inside a php single quate? i am trying backslash example: value = \'@/\' + name + \'/\'; but it not works

Comment: Not sure for php, but check this: http://coredogs.com/lesson/magic-quotes-and-strings

Answer (score 2):

```
function update(name){
    document.getElementById('comment_content').value = '@/' + name + '/';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for remark. I lost sight of that `var` is a reserved word. Given that you have answered first and corrected your answer, I deleted my.